# Passing in functions to Backbone.View.extend

Tags: javascript, coding-style, backbone.js, conventions

Recently I'm having an argument with some co-workers about something that I 
find incorrect. 
We're using Backbone in a large application and my way to create views is 
the 'standard' backbone way :

```
var MyView = Backbone.View.extend({ 
  className: 'foo', 
  initialize: function() { 
    _.bindAll(this, 'render' /* ... more stuff */); 
  }, 
  render: function() { 
    /* ... render, usually 
      using _.template and passing 
      in this.model.toJSON()... */ 
    return this; 
  } 
});
```

But someone in the team recently decided to do it this way :

```
var MyView = Backbone.View.extend( (function() { 
  /* 'private stuff' */ 
  function bindMethods(view) { 
    _.bindAll(view, /* ... more stuff */); 
  }; 
  function render(view) { 
     /* ... render, usually 
        using _.template and passing 
        in view.model.toJSON()... */ 
  }; 
  return { 
    className: 'foo', 
    initialize: function() { 
      bindMethods(this); 
      render(this);   
    } 
  }; 
}());
```

That's the idea in pseudo-code . 
Having read the BB source and read tutorials, articles I find this to be a 
bad practice (for me it makes no sense), but I'd love some feedback from 
other Backbone developers/users

Thanks in advance

Comment: Personally, I don't see a need to put a view in a closure like that, it decreases readability.

Comment: Much agreed. It's unreadable ... but more than that I think this can lead to confusion. Thanks for your feedback

Answer (score 2):

One benefit I see from using the closure is providing a private scope for variables and functions that you don't want to be accessible from code outside the view.

Even so, I haven't seen many Backbone apps use a closure to define a view/model/collection etc.

Here's an email from Jeremy Ashkenas concerning this issue as well.

> Yes, using closures to create instances of objects with private variables is possible in JavaScript. But it's a bad practice, and should be avoided. This has nothing to do with Backbone in particular; it's the nature of OOP in JavaScript.
>
> If you use the closure pattern (also known as the "module" pattern), you're creating a new copy of each function for each instance you create. This completely ignores prototypes, and is terribly inefficient both in terms of speed and especially in terms of memory use. If you make 10,000 models, you'll also have 10,000 copies of each member function. With prototypes (with Backbone.Model.extend), you'll only have a single copy of each member function, even if there are 10,000 instances of the class.

Comment: Yes, that was the main goal of this 'self invoking' function.
Thanks for the feedback

Comment: Well, here's an update on the same topic I posted on the Backbone google discussion group,  https://groups.google.com/group/backbonejs/browse_thread/thread/7a748cf87e2dcd74

This should be definetly avoided

Answer (score 0):

I totally agree with Paul here. Sometimes you may find it necessary to define methods and properties that are private and can't be messed with from outside. I think it depends wether you need this scoping mechanism in your class or not. Mixing both approaches, with respect to the requirements you have for the class wouldn't be so bad, would it?